# Regex error at runtime Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2019

I am sure many of people have asked the same question like this one but I'll ask it anyway.
I am reading a line from file that looks like this

```
{"Depth":32,"NL":1,"NS":0,"Type":"RGBA"}
```

I want to parse out 32,1,0,RGBA into their specific variables.
Here is the regex:

```
std::regex rx("\{\"Depth\":([0-9]{2}),\"NL\":([0-9]),\"NS\":([0-9]),\"Type\":\"([A-Z]{4})\"\}");
```

https://regex101.com/ this website says that the regex is correct in multiple standards. I use Visual Studio 2019 and its default standard. Could that be an issue?

Comment: That looks like JSON, why aren't you using a JSON parser library?

Comment: Use a raw-string-literal for your regex, and you can avoid all the backslashes.

Comment: @Barmar it is JSON. It is a university project. I am allowed to use the library to write to json file but I am specifically told to use regex to read the file that we wrote.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Barmar Microsoft C++ exception: std::regex_error

Comment: Since you're not using a raw string, you need to double the backslashes before `{` and `}`.

Comment: @Barmar you're a life savior! You;ve just saved me from a night of frustration. I works now.